# Non finite transformation detected - lidR spTransform

Tags: r, lidar, sp, lidr

I would like to re project the [following laz file](ftp://rockyftp.cr.usgs.gov/vdelivery/Datasets/Staged/Elevation/LPC/Projects/USGS_LPC_CA_FEMA_R9_Russian_2017_LAS_2018/laz/USGS_LPC_CA_FEMA_R9_Russian_2017_10SDJ993053_LAS_2018.laz) using `lidR` and `spTransform` from `sp`.
The EPSG code is not defined but it seems to me that the CRS string is complete:

```
tmp_laz <- readLAS("./USGS_LPC_CA_FEMA_R9_Russian_2017_10SDJ993053_LAS_2018.laz")
epsg(tmp_laz)
#>[1] 0
tmp_laz@proj4string@projargs
#> [1] "+proj=lcc +lat_0=37.6666666666667 +lon_0=-122 +lat_1=39.8333333333333 +lat_2=38.3333333333333 +x_0=2000000.0001016 +y_0=500000.0001016 +ellps=GRS80 +units=us-ft +vunits=us-ft +no_defs"
```

I tried to project to the global metric datum [EPSG 3857](https://epsg.io/3857) and got the following error `non finite transformation detected:`

```
tmp_laz_2 <- spTransform(tmp_laz, sp::CRS("+init=epsg:3857") )
#> non finite transformation detected:
#>   X       Y        
#> [1,] 6275252 2094773 Inf Inf
#> [2,] 6275249 2094771 Inf Inf
#> [3,] 6275246 2094769 Inf Inf
#> [4,] 6275243 2094768 Inf Inf
#> [5,] 6275251 2094768 Inf Inf
#> [6,] 6275251 2094775 Inf Inf
#> [7,] 6275248 2094774 Inf Inf
#> [8,] 6275245 2094772 Inf Inf
#> [9,] 6275242 2094770 Inf Inf
#> [10,] 6275239 2094768 Inf Inf
#> ... goes on till reaching print limit
#> Erreur : C stack usage  100062272 is too close to the limit
#> De plus : Warning messages:
#>   1: In showSRID(uprojargs, format = "PROJ", multiline = "NO") :
#>   Discarded ellps WGS 84 in CRS definition: +proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +k=1 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs
#> 2: In showSRID(uprojargs, format = "PROJ", multiline = "NO") :
#>   Discarded datum WGS_1984 in CRS definition
#> 3: In sp::proj4string(x) : CRS object has comment, which is lost in output
#> 4: In sp::spTransform(spts, CRSobj) :
#>   12346945 projected point(s) not finite
```

I tried another (local) projection, [EPSG 6417](https://epsg.io/3857) and got the same error:

```
tmp_laz_6417 <- spTransform(tmp_laz, sp::CRS("+init=epsg:6417") )

#> non finite transformation detected:
#>   X       Y        
#> [1,] 6275252 2094773 Inf Inf
#> [2,] 6275249 2094771 Inf Inf
#> [3,] 6275246 2094769 Inf Inf
#> [4,] 6275243 2094768 Inf Inf
#> [5,] 6275251 2094768 Inf Inf
#> [6,] 6275251 2094775 Inf Inf
#> [7,] 6275248 2094774 Inf Inf
#> [8,] 6275245 2094772 Inf Inf
#> [9,] 6275242 2094770 Inf Inf
#> [10,] 6275239 2094768 Inf Inf
#> ... goes on till reaching print limit

#> Erreur : C stack usage  100062272 is too close to the limit
#> De plus : Warning messages:
#>   1: In showSRID(uprojargs, format = "PROJ", multiline = "NO") :
#>   Discarded datum NAD83_National_Spatial_Reference_System_2011 in CRS definition
#> 2: In sp::proj4string(x) : CRS object has comment, which is lost in output
#> 3: In sp::spTransform(spts, CRSobj) :
#>   12346945 projected point(s) not finite
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, many questions here

### epsg is 0

Your file is a LAS 1.4. It does not store the projection with an epsg code but with a WKT string. `epsg()` should error (or at least warn) and tell you that your las file does not store epsg code but WKT string. But it returns 0 instead. Improvable design...

```r
tmp_las@header
#> File signature:           LASF 
#> File source ID:           0 
#> Global encoding:
#>  - GPS Time Type: Standard GPS Time 
#>  - Synthetic Return Numbers: no 
#>  - Well Know Text: CRS is WKT 
#>  - Aggregate Model: false 
#> [...]
#> Variable length records: 
#>    Variable length record 1 of 3 
#>        Description: OGC WKT Coordinate System 
#>        WKT OGC COORDINATE SYSTEM: COMPD_CS["NAD83(2011) / California zone 2 (ftUS) + NAVD88 height - Geo [...] (truncated)
#> [...]
```

### non finite transformation detected

This one is an `sp` related issue. I'm not an expert in projection and transformation so I can't help you. You should ask another specific question with focused tag. My guess is that you are trying to convert incompatible things. Here a minimal, standalone, reproducible example with 3 points only:

```r
X = c(6275235.88, 6275229.48, 6275163.35)
Y = c(2094771.54, 2094815.15, 2094777.31)
WKT = "COMPD_CS[\"NAD83(2011) / California zone 2 (ftUS) + NAVD88 height - Geoid12B (ftUS)\",PROJCS[\"NAD83(2011) / California zone 2 (ftUS)\",GEOGCS[\"NAD83(2011)\",DATUM[\"NAD83_National_Spatial_Reference_System_2011\",SPHEROID[\"GRS 1980\",6378137,298.257222101,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"7019\"]],AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"1116\"]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"8901\"]],UNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"9122\"]],AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"6318\"]],PROJECTION[\"Lambert_Conformal_Conic_2SP\"],PARAMETER[\"standard_parallel_1\",39.83333333333334],PARAMETER[\"standard_parallel_2\",38.33333333333334],PARAMETER[\"latitude_of_origin\",37.66666666666666],PARAMETER[\"central_meridian\",-122],PARAMETER[\"false_easting\",6561666.667],PARAMETER[\"false_northing\",1640416.667],UNIT[\"US survey foot\",0.3048006096012192,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"9003\"]],AXIS[\"X\",EAST],AXIS[\"Y\",NORTH],AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"6418\"]],VERT_CS[\"NAVD88 height - Geoid12B (ftUS)\",VERT_DATUM[\"North American Vertical Datum 1988\",2005,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"5103\"]],UNIT[\"US survey foot\",0.3048006096012192,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"9003\"]],AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"6360\"]]]"
XY = cbind(X,Y)
XY = sp::SpatialPoints(XY, sp::CRS(SRS_string = WKT))
sp::spTransform(XY, sp::CRS("+init=epsg:3857"))
#> Warning in sp::spTransform(XY, sp::CRS("+init=epsg:3857")): 3 projected point(s)
#> not finite
#> non finite transformation detected:
#>            X       Y        
#> [1,] 6275236 2094772 Inf Inf
#> [2,] 6275229 2094815 Inf Inf
#> [3,] 6275163 2094777 Inf Inf
#> Error in sp::spTransform(XY, sp::CRS("+init=epsg:3857")): failure in points 1:2:3
```

<sup>Created on 2020-10-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

### C stack usage

This one is likely because your point cloud is big. I didn't reproduce because I only loaded a fraction of the data but I'm pretty sure it is related to the amount of data. As mentioned in the post you linked, `spTransform` is only a convenience for small datasets but it is not recommended to use to perform big transformation because it is inherently sub optimal in term of memory usage as it creates a copy of the coordinates in `sp` format. Using `las2las` from LAStools is more advised.

You can give it a try anyway once you solved your non finite transformation. Maybe it is related and it will work.

Comment: Thanks! I have posted a new thread (https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/375540/non-finite-transformation-detected-using-sp-r) for the sp part of this post